# The method xxx is undefined for the type ListRSSItemsActivity

Tags: android, eclipse, string, rss, undefined

I am getting the following error:

ERROR:

- The method access$3() is undefined for the type ListRSSItemsActivity
- The method access$2() is undefined for the type ListRSSItemsActivity
- The method access$4() is undefined for the type ListRSSItemsActivity
- The method access$5() is undefined for the type ListRSSItemsActivity

Here is the code, please help me figure out where I am going wrong?

For ListRSSItemsActivity.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ListRSSItemsActivity extends ListActivity
{
  private static String TAG_DESRIPTION;
  private static String TAG_GUID;
  private static String TAG_LINK;
  private static String TAG_PUB_DATE;
  private static String TAG_TITLE = "title";
  ImageButton btnAddSite;
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  RSSFeed rssFeed;
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rssItemList = new ArrayList();
  List<RSSItem> rssItems = new ArrayList();
  RSSParser rssParser = new RSSParser();

  static
  {
    TAG_LINK = "link";
    TAG_DESRIPTION = "description";
    TAG_PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
    TAG_GUID = "guid";
  }

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.rss_item_list);
    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("candidat");
    new loadRSSFeedItems().execute(new String[] { str });
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong)
      {
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(ListRSSItemsActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), DisPlayWebPageActivity.class);
        localIntent.putExtra("page_url", ((TextView)paramView.findViewById(R.id.page_url)).getText().toString());
        ListRSSItemsActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
      }
    });
  }

  class loadRSSFeed extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
  {
    loadRSSFeed()
    {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    {
      String str1 = paramArrayOfString[0];
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed = ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssParser.getRSSFeed(str1);
      Log.d("rssFeed", "rssFeed: " + ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed);
      Log.d("rssFeed", "url: " + str1);
      if (ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed != null)
      {
        Log.e("RSS URL", ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed.getTitle() + ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed.getLink() + ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed.getDescription() + ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed.getLanguage());
        WebSite localWebSite = new WebSite(ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed.getTitle(), ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed.getLink(), ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed.getRSSLink(), ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssFeed.getDescription());
        HashMap localHashMap = new HashMap();
        localHashMap.put(ListRSSItemsActivity.TAG_TITLE, localWebSite.getTitle());
        localHashMap.put(ListRSSItemsActivity.TAG_LINK, localWebSite.getLink());
        String str2 = localWebSite.getDescription();
        if (str2.length() > 100)
          str2 = str2.substring(0, 97) + "..";
        localHashMap.put(ListRSSItemsActivity.TAG_DESRIPTION, str2);
        ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssItemList.add(localHashMap);
      }
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
      {
        public void run()
        {
          ListRSSItemsActivity localListRSSItemsActivity = ListRSSItemsActivity.this;
          ArrayList localArrayList = ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssItemList;
          String[] arrayOfString = new String[4];
          arrayOfString[0] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$3();
          arrayOfString[1] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$2();
          arrayOfString[2] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$4();
          arrayOfString[3] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$5();
         SimpleAdapter localSimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(localListRSSItemsActivity, localArrayList, R.layout.rss_item_list_row, arrayOfString, new int[] { R.id.page_url, R.id.title, R.id.pub_date, R.id.link });
          ListRSSItemsActivity.this.setListAdapter(localSimpleAdapter);
        }
      });
      return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String paramString)
    {
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
      super.onPreExecute();
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListRSSItemsActivity.this);
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.setMessage("Fetching RSS Information ...");
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.setCancelable(false);
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.show();
    }
  }

  class loadRSSFeedItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
  {
    loadRSSFeedItems()
    {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String[] paramArrayOfString)
    {
      String str1 = paramArrayOfString[0];
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssItems = ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssParser.getRSSFeedItems(str1);
      Iterator localIterator = ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssItems.iterator();
      while (true)
      {
        if (!localIterator.hasNext())
        {
          ListRSSItemsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
          {
            public void run()
            {
              ListRSSItemsActivity localListRSSItemsActivity = ListRSSItemsActivity.this;
              ArrayList localArrayList = ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssItemList;
              String[] arrayOfString = new String[4];
              arrayOfString[0] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$3();
              arrayOfString[1] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$2();
              arrayOfString[2] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$4();
              arrayOfString[3] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$5();
             SimpleAdapter localSimpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(localListRSSItemsActivity, localArrayList, R.layout.rss_item_list_row, arrayOfString, new int[] { R.id.page_url, R.id.title, R.id.pub_date, R.id.link });
              ListRSSItemsActivity.this.setListAdapter(localSimpleAdapter);
            }
          });
          return null;
        }
        RSSItem localRSSItem = (RSSItem)localIterator.next();
        HashMap localHashMap = new HashMap();
        localHashMap.put(ListRSSItemsActivity.TAG_TITLE, localRSSItem.getTitle());
        Log.d("Link", localRSSItem.getLink());
        localHashMap.put(ListRSSItemsActivity.TAG_LINK, localRSSItem.getLink());
        localHashMap.put(ListRSSItemsActivity.TAG_PUB_DATE, localRSSItem.getPubdate());
        String str2 = localRSSItem.getDescription();
        if (str2.length() > 100)
          str2 = str2.substring(0, 97) + "..";
        localHashMap.put(ListRSSItemsActivity.TAG_DESRIPTION, str2);
        ListRSSItemsActivity.this.rssItemList.add(localHashMap);
      }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String paramString)
    {
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
      super.onPreExecute();
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListRSSItemsActivity.this);
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.setMessage("Loading recent articles...");
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.setCancelable(false);
      ListRSSItemsActivity.this.pDialog.show();
    }
  }
}
```

For rss_item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:background="#ffffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:divider="#ffbababa" android:dividerHeight="1.0dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using Eclipse & API 19.1 SDK

Comment: Where have u defind the methods ??

Comment: @panther   arrayOfString[0] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$3();
              arrayOfString[1] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$2();
              arrayOfString[2] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$4();
              arrayOfString[3] = ListRSSItemsActivity.access$5();

Comment: I mean method definition, not the place your are uisng it.

Comment: @panther on ListRSSItemsActivity.java?

Comment: ya.. ListRSSItemsActivity.access$2() seems there must be a static method in this name on the class `ListRSSItemsActivity`